# How to solve the problem with installing GRUB in Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, grub, vmware

I am trying to install Arch Linux in VMware and I have problems with GRUB:

in:

```bsh
grub-install /dev/sda --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot
```

out:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory.
```

in:

```bsh
grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
```

out:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partitionl; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding os not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and theur use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Are there any other ways to install GRUB? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you set up your VM as an EFI system? The error suggests you are trying to install EFI grub on a non-EFI system.

Comment: @terdon i also tried install bios-version ```grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda``` or is it not?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're quite right. I missed the second part. But why i386? Surely you have a 64bit system. What happens if you just run `grub-install  /dev/sda`? I haven't used grub in years, but I have never needed this `--target` option.

Comment: @terdon same error

Comment: @GAD3R exactly partition? I can not install it in a folder, or something else?

Comment: @GAD3R I tried to do as it is written in the answer and when i used the command modprobe efivars i got en error ``` modprobe FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/5.2.11-arch1-1-ARCH ```

Comment: @GAD3R ty write an answer and I will mark it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insatll grub on a GUID Partition Table with bios mode you need to create a bios_boot partition.

[GUID Partition Table (GPT) specific instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_(GPT)_specific_instructions)

> On a BIOS/GPT configuration, a [BIOS boot partition](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/BIOS-installation.html#BIOS-installation) is required. GRUB embeds its core.img into this partition.
>
> The BIOS boot partition is only needed by GRUB on a BIOS/GPT setup